# How to disable <p:tab>

Tags: primefaces

I want to disable **<*p:tab*>** using **<*p:commandButton*>**

**File.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="tabUserModule">
    <p:tabView value="#{listModule.toArray()}" var="car" id="tabView1" widgetVar="delg1">

        <p:tab title="#{car[0].module}" id="styleChoix" disabled="#{disableTag.disableTa}" >

            <p:tabView orientation="left"  >

                <p:tab title=" Prototype " >
                   <h:panelGrid >
        <p:commandButton value="Disable" oncomplete="delg1.select(0)" 
        action="#{disableTag.buttonAction}" update=":tabUserModule:tabView1:styleChoix"/>
 .....
```

**Bean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DisableTag implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7179479455651980518L;

private boolean disableTa=false;

public boolean isDisableTa() {
    return disableTa;
}

public void setDisableTa(boolean disableTa) {
    this.disableTa = disableTa;
}

public void buttonAction()
{
    disableTa = true;
}
}
```

But when i execute this code all tab are disabled so how can i solve this issue plz?

[image]

i want to disable **tab** surrounded by orange

Comment: what version of primefaces are you using?

Comment: hey. what have you solved this question?

Answer (score 0):

You should **change** your update attribute to

```
update=":tabUserModule:tabView1"
```

only instead of your original "*:tabUserModule:tabView1:styleChoix*"

This means you have to update the whole p:tabView element instead of a specific tab only. Because upon inspection of the rendered html, this is a `disabled="false"` of your tab having the `<div>` as the `<p:tabView>` and the `<li>` and `<a>` combination as your individual `<p:tab>`:

```
<div id="tabUserModule:tabView1" ...>
   <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" ...>
      <a href="#tabUserModule:tabView1:styleChoix">....</a>
   </li> 
</div>
```

but with `disabled="true"` it is rendered as:

```
<div id="tabUserModule:tabView1" ...>
   <li class="ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-corner-top ui-state-disabled" ...>
      <a href="#tabUserModule:tabView1:styleChoix">....</a>
   </li> 
</div>
```

Notice the addition of the `ui-state-disabled` in the class attribute of the `<li>` tag which causes it to be disabled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Even if i change **:tabUserModule:tabView1:styleChoix** by `update=":tabUserModule:tabView1` it is not working, I still have the same issue

Comment: do you see any error output in the browser or in your server? that's weird because I even tried it myself and it worked

Comment: what other elements have the  disabled="#{disableTag.disableTa}" attribute? can you add more details in your file.xhtml?

Comment: there is no other element

Comment: even in the browser console (F12) there is no error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89901/discussion-between-user3693890-and-fritz).